# Where do you go in your files to change the default text size?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am working on going through the products and making all of the descriptions look the same, and I have been using the wysiwyg editor to change the text size. I was wondering if there was somewhere in the files I could go to change the font size each time I write a new description.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the displayed product description font size via css in the frontend you will not need to change it from wysiwyg editor in backend

Comment: But for future products so I don't have to worry about making sure the text is in the proper size everytime